# Every measure of natural numbers and the power of natural numbers as their sigma algebra looks like this....

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let X= $ \mathbb{N} $ ans S=  ***P***($ \mathbb{N} $) . Prove that every measure $\mu $ in  $(X,\mathcal S)$ can be obtained by an unique  non-negative extended sequence of real numbers $(a_{n})$ as follows :

$\mu(E)= \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }E=\varnothing,\\
\sum_{n \in E } (a_{n}) & \text{if } E \not=  \varnothing
.
\end{cases}
$

I have no ideas proving this problem that as far as i know says that every measure of natural numbers that have the power of naturals as a sigma-algebra seems like the above. The only think i can see is that this is a measure so any help in order to prove this will be welcome. Thanks

Comment: You might start by considering whether, for a given measure $\mu$, defining the sequence $a_n=\mu(\{n\})$ meets the requirements, and then whether this is unique for that measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should have, given the measure $\mu$, a sequence to be your candidate. Then you prove that this candidate is unique.

Every set $E \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ can be written as the union of his elements (note that this union is enumerable and disjoint).

So, write $E = \{e_1,..,e_n,... \}$, then, using that $E = \cup_n \{e_n\} $ and the properties of a measure you have $$ \mu(E) = \sum_n \mu(\{e_n\})$$

Now you have your candidate. Let $a_n = \mu(\{n\})$. So,
$$\mu(E) = \sum_{n \in E} \mu(\{n\})$$

This proves the existence. Now, suppose you have another sequence, $(b_n)_n$ with the same property you mentioned. Then apply the result for $E=\{n\}$ you came up with
$$\mu(E)=\mu(\{n\})=a_n=b_n$$ by the defition of $a_n$ and by the fact $b_n$ satisfy the condition you wrote above.

Hope this can help.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: De nada! Sem problemas! =)